# WebML frameworks or tools

Tags: frameworks, uml

I was asked about this, someone mentioned me about [Webratio](http://webratio.com), is there any othe tool or framework comparable to this, preferable oss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. WebML was created by the same people that founded WebRatio. Even if now they are trying to push it as a [standard OMG web modeling language](http://modeling-languages.com/towards-standardization-web-modeling-language/) I don't think right now there are other tools that support it.

Answer (score 1):

Jordi, you are right. As far as I know there are no other industrial implementations of WebML.
[WebRatio](http://www.webratio.com) is not opensource, but it can be downloaded for free for non commercial purposes.
Furthermore, along the line of standardizing the [WebML](http://www.webml.org) language within [OMG](http://www.omg.org) (under the name of [IFML](http://www.ifml.org)), we plan to release an opensource modeling tool.

OOH4RIA is a valid option, although experimental, but is not covering the WebML notation. It's instead based on an extension of the OOH notation for rich interfaces.

[Disclaimer: I'm with Politecnico di Milano and WebRatio, and among the inventors of WebML/IFML]

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ooh4RIA](http://suma2.dlsi.ua.es/ooh4ria/screenshot.html) could be an option.